# Emploi métaphorique de l'interjection "Amen"

Tags: usage, religion, métaphore

Le mot (interjection) "Amen", en dehors de la connotation religieuse, a aussi un sens métaphorique signifiant, p.ex., la fin d'un discours. TLFi en parle :

> P. plaisant. Signifie la fin d'un discours, d'un récit, d'une histoire, d'une controverse... :
>
> 3. − S'il vous échappe une indiscrétion, messieurs, dit-il [Maxime de Trailles] j'aurai votre sang ou vous aurez le mien. − Amen, lui répondit Gobseck (...) Pour jouer son sang, faut en avoir, mon petit ... H. de Balzac, Gobseck,1830, p. 415.
> 4. Au reste, n'avoir, − car je n'en ai, presque, aucun ressentiment contre lui, − c'est impliquer qu'on le considère dorénavant comme un être sans vraie valeur personnelle, sans personnalité et quasi irresponsable, ou ne m'intéressant que peu, ou agissant selon des mobiles que je ne puis pas approuver. Amen et ainsi soit-il et tant pis. A. Gide, P. Valéry, Correspondance,lettre de A. G. à P. V., mars 1895, p. 235.

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amen

Tous deux extraits sont vieux quand même. De nos jours peut-on utiliser couramment "amen" hors du contexte religieux ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je ne suis pas d'accord sur votre décision concernant la réponse suivante https://french.stackexchange.com/a/39995/17649  La question de ne pas utiliser le mot du tout est  seulement une conséquence logique, une question de rester consistent si on juge que l'emploi *plus ou moins en public* est à déconseiller. Je peux bien sûr faire une modification pour rendre cela explicite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui tu peux l'utiliser hors contexte religieux, pour ma part je l'emploie ou l'entends pour deux choses :

**1) Marquer le soulagement**

Par exemple si j'apprends que finalement, un réalisateur que je n'apprécie pas a été évincé d'un film que j'attends beaucoup. Ou si je cours autour d'une piste depuis trente minutes et que, enfin, mon entraîneur siffle la fin de l'entraînement.

> Amen !

**2) Marquer le fait que quelque chose aurait dû être fait depuis longtemps**

L'équivalent de "c'est pas trop tôt", par exemple si le gouvernement sort une loi que tout le monde réclame depuis des années, ou que mes enfants ont enfin mis la table comme je l'ai demandé il y a une heure.

> Amen...

---

Tu noteras que les sens sont très proches, en fait je dirais que le deuxième est simplement un détournement sarcastique du premier (qui lui-même est déjà un emploi détourné), tu pourrais d'ailleurs intervertir les situations que j'ai données en exemples selon que ta réaction et ton emploi de "amen" seraient plutôt un soulagement sincère ou une remarque sarcastique.

J'ajoute que cette utilisation relève malgré tout du langage courant voire familier, disons qu'elle est à proscrire lors d'un discours politique où la connotation religieuse sera immédiatement relevée par tout le monde. Mais je ne pense pas qu'en société, même en présence de personnes en costume et buvant du champagne, cela sera mal pris.

Comment: Oui absolument pour le côté que tu dis *ironique*. Je dirais même que (cf. citation Gide dans l'OP) HORS contexte religieux, je ne le crois employé QU'avec une nuance **sarcastique**.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je vais changer "ironique" par "sarcastique" en effet.

Comment: On peut aussi mentionner l'expression "dire amen à tout", qui signifie tout accepter sans discuter.